# Extensive Renovations during 60 days notice

Tags: canada, ontario

I gave 60 days notice and the landlord seems to think they are starting extensive renovations during my 60 days.

What rights do I have about not being disturbed and privacy and not having my possessions moved or touched and being left in peace?

They are rotten people and I don't want to cooperate at all if I don't have to.

Ontario, Canada

Comment: By seems to think, you mean the landlord has expressed to you that during those dates, whenever they are, renovation work will commence?

Answer (score 1):

Throughout your time as a tenant you have a right to "[quiet enjoyment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance)" of the premises. Renovation of the property is not consistent with this.

The landlord (including their agents) can enter your property only as provided in the lease and tenancy law.